# There is $1$ white ball, and $3$ black balls, what is the probability of getting $2$ black balls?

Tags: probability

There is $1$ white ball, and $3$ black balls, what is the probability of getting $2$ black balls?

$3 \choose 2$ of the black balls divided by $4 \choose 2$???
doesn't seem right? :(

Explanation: I checked ways of getting $2$ black balls out of three divided by total outcomes of picking two balls out of $4$

Comment: Please make an effort.  Write a coherent question, at least.

Comment: And use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematical terms and notation.

Comment: Question seems pretty straightforward what is so incoherent avout it ?

Comment: I updated my thought process on post. sorry

Comment: The question is not clearly written.  If you meant that two balls are randomly selected without replacement from a box containing one white ball and three black balls, you should explicitly state that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m considering that you are picking 2 balls out of it and not putting the first ball you picked, back. So the elements you have are: $\space W, B1, B2, B3$.

The sample space, which consists of all possible outcomes of the experiment is:

$\Omega = \{(W,B1), (W,B2), (W,B3),\\ \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space  (B1,W), (B1,B2), (B1,B3),\\ \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space (B2,W),(B2,B1),(B2,B3), \\  \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space  (B3,W), (B3,B1), (B3,B2)\}$

Therefore, out of 12 possible outcomes, 6 of them will consist of two black balls. Probability equals $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Same result as realizing the probability of drawing first a black ball is $\frac 34$, and with not replacement, there are remaining 2 black and one white balls, so probability of second draw being black is $2/3$  Rule of the product: probability of drawing two black balls is $\frac 34 \times \frac 23 = \frac 24=\frac 12$